# Sending email with attachment from S3 Bucket using SES in Boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, events, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ses

I have been following this question

[Python Lambda to send files uploaded to s3 as email attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320376/python-lambda-to-send-files-uploaded-to-s3-as-email-attachments)

When I run the Lambda function, I encounter the following error.

Any piece of advice is much appreciated.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'Records'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 31, in lambda_handler\n    FILEOBJ = event[\"Records\"][0]\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The `KeyError` indicates that there is either no `Records` entry in `event["Records"]`, or there is no zero-index record in `event["Records"][0]`. You can add a debug statement such as `print(event)` to view the contents of the `event` record in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: How are you running the code? Are you clicking **Test**, or is the AWS Lambda function being triggered somehow? Please edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: @John Rotenstein Thanks for your kind advice. printing the event helped in realizing that there was a type in sender email address. After fixing it, I uploaded a file into S3 and it worked :)