# How do I add an attachment to a daily scheduled email in AWS, SES, Lambda, Cloudwatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

1). I have found a piece of code (below) in Node.js which allows me to send an email alert at 9am which works fine. I need to further develop this so that it will attach the latest file from an S3 bucket.

2). I have found other code in Python which will send an email with the file attached as soon as it is uploaded to the S3 bucket.

I can't get the extra functionality from 2 to work in 1.

Below is the code for the function which successfully schedules an email but I need to be able to attach the latest file in an S3 bucket. I also don't know the name of the file as it will be uploaded by someone else.

All I need to do is to send the latest file in the S3 bucket as an attachment at 9am daily.
I have the Cloudwatch schedule feature already setup.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-west-2'
})
const ses = new AWS.SES();
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   const params = {
       Destination: {
           ToAddresses: ['abc@abc.com']
       },
       Message: {
           Subject: {Data: 'Daily Email'},
           Body: {
               Text: {Data: 'Hello: \n\n Good Morning: Here is your 9am Alert!!! \n\n'}
           }
       },
   
       Source: 'xyz@xyz.com'
   };
   await ses.sendEmail(params).promise().then(response => {
       console.log('Successfully sent email!!!');
   }, error => {
       console.error('An error occured while attempting to send email: ', error);
   })
};
```

I managed to get a Python version working, which sends the attachment, but for some reason it doesn't include the file name to the attachment? It gives the attachment name as a string of random characters.

Does anyone know how to include the file attachment name to the attached file & which part of my code would be causing the issue? I know the attachment name as "TEST.pdf" can I just add the name to the successfully attached file?

```
import boto3
import os.path
import email
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ses = boto3.client("ses")
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    AWS_REGION = "aws_region"
    
    bucket_name = 'testing'
    
    object_name = 'TEST.pdf'
        
    fileObj = s3.get_object( Key=object_name, Bucket='testing')
    
    key = str(fileObj)
        
    sender = "abc@abc.com"
    to = "xyz@xyz.com"
    subject = 'Email from abc'
    body = """Hello, xyz Please see the attached file related to recent submission.
    <br>
    This email is from blahblahblah:
    """
    
    file_name = os.path.basename(key)
    
    tmp_file_name = '/tmp/' +file_name
    
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, object_name, tmp_file_name)
    
    ATTACHMENT= tmp_file_name
#    att= tmp_file_name
    
    # The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
    BODY_TEXT = "Hello, xyz Please see the attached file related to recent submission."

    # The HTML body of the email.
    BODY_HTML = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello!!!</h1>
    <p>Please see the attached file related to TEST.pdf latest upload to S3 Bucket.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    # The character encoding for the email.
    CHARSET = "utf-8"

    # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

    # Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    # Add subject, from and to lines.
    msg['Subject'] = subject 
    msg['From'] = sender 
    msg['To'] = to

    # Create a multipart/alternative child container.
    msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    # Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
    # necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.
    textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
    htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)

    # Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msg_body.attach(textpart)
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

    # Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
    att = MIMEApplication(open(ATTACHMENT, 'rb').read())

    # Add a header to tell the email client to treat this part as an attachment,
    # and to give the attachment a name.
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=os.path.basename(ATTACHMENT))

    # Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
    # parent container.
    msg.attach(msg_body)

    # Add the attachment to the parent container.
    msg.attach(att)
    print(msg)
    try:
        #Provide the contents of the email.
        response = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=sender,
            Destinations=[
                to
            ],
            RawMessage={
                'Data':msg.as_string(),
            },
    #        ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET
        )
    # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
        print(response['MessageId'])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - do you mean latest file from a specific "folder"? the latest file across the bucket? what have you already tried? your code is also invalid Node.js code so please fic the code and show us what you've tried and what is not working and we can help you from there.

Comment: meanwhile, you can give a shot at this article [link](https://medium.com/@xoor/sending-emails-with-attachments-with-aws-lambda-and-node-js-e6a78500227c)

Comment: Hi Ermiya here is a python example which works & is triggered when ever a file is uploaded. It sends the file straight away: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56320376/16457936 I want to be able to send the latest file as an attachment at a specific time every day.

Comment: I have managed to get a Python version which successfully attaches the file working but there is an issue when it names the file. It just gives it a random string of chars. I can just add the required file name as I know it "TEST.pdf" how would I add this feature to my Python code above?