# E-mailing CSV file from S3 without downloading it using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need an application to pick up some `csv` files from an `s3 bucket` and e-mail them to specified recipients. I was able to make the code work using the solution present at the end of the question here:
[Python Lambda to send files uploaded to s3 as email attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320376/python-lambda-to-send-files-uploaded-to-s3-as-email-attachments)

However, this code solution above first downloads the files entirely to `local storage`, then reads them again and e-mails them. My company strongly prefers I find a solution to e-mail the attachment directly from `s3` without having to rely on `local storage`. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Note**: I am not using an `AWS Lambda`, just a regular python application run from a server, unlike the question I refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You could design your python application running on the server to send the email via `serverless` application, say. The `serverless` app would download the object from s3, before attaching it to the email and sending it.

[AWS supports python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html), and `serverless` [has an SDK](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/sdk/python) for python development.

The sequence of events would look something like

```
Actor
 |
Python App
 |
Lambda <-> s3
 |
 `
Email Server
 |
User
```